# How to set Authentication in apache bloodhound?

Tags: trac, apache-bloodhound

I've just installed Apache Bloodhound in my server. It's working fine. But with the default settings, anyone can view the list of tickets. I want to change this so that only logged in users are able to view the tickets.

Is it possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default Trac ticket permissions are TICKET_VIEW for 'anonymous' sessions (everyone) and editing for 'authenticated' users, yes.

You'll want to remove TICKET_VIEW, so only authenticated users will see (and modify) tickets. To accomplish that, any user with PERMISSION_REVOKE (inherited by TRAC_ADMIN and PERMISSION_ADMIN as well) is allowed to navigate to the [permission web admin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPermissions) page, can check and submit the 'remove' action. Alternatively you could use the [trac-admin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracAdmin) command:

```
trac-admin <path_to_trac_env> permission remove anonymous TICKET_VIEW
```

where you need to replace the path with you real one, like `/var/www/trac_env/myTrac`.